# What is the equivalent of MSG_WAITALL for CFReadStream sockets in swift?

Tags: swift

I have created TCP/IP read/write streams using `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost()` and use the `stream(_ aStream:Stream, handle eventCode:Stream.Event) {}` delegate method to obtain responses from my target.

All works well when the target sends fairly short messages (say < 200 bytes). When the target sends 1K messages, they are broken up into 2 or more actual messages. Nothing wrong with that, TCP/IP does that sort of thing. With "normal" sockets (in c or python), I can set a flag on the `socket.recv()` method to indicate that I want the entire message to be assembled and in my buffer with flag = `socket.MSG_WAITALL`.

Is there a way to do this in swift? the `inputStream.read()` method only has two arguments; `buffer` and `maxLength` but not a facility to tell it not to give me partial results.

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/PollingVersusRunloop.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002275-CJBEDDBG

Comment: nope - that reference is for writing to a stream not reading from. Secondly, the sidebar that does take me to some discussion on reading from a stream does not describe a socket.MSG_WAITALL style way of handling multiple tcp/ip packets as part of one message.

Comment: Oh well. :( I tried...